# non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context while following a java book

Tags: java

I'm new to java and following a book called "Learn java in 21 days". while Following it i was writing a piece of code similar to the one written in book but it gave an error of "non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context" while in the book the author is getting proper output and he didn't mention about the error. Can any one please tell me what is this error? i have tried checking this problem but i'm unable to understand as in book there is no error but in my code its shown as error. I'm using NetBeans.

i tried replacing float's F or decimal points etc

```
  package com.java21days;
  import java.util.*;
  public class ComicBooks{

  public ComicBooks() {
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap quality = new HashMap();
    // Setting of hash
    float price1 = 3.00F;
    quality.put("mint", price1);
    float price2 = 2.00F;
    quality.put("Near mint", price2);
    float price3 = 1.50F;
    quality.put("Very Fine", price3);
    float price4 = 1.00F;
    quality.put("Fine", price4);
    float price5 = 0.50F;
    quality.put("Good", price5);
    float price6 = 0.25F;
    quality.put("poor", price6);
    // Getting Values
    Comic[] comix = new Comic[3]; // array of Commic objects
    comix[0] = new Comic("Amazing Spider-Man", "1A", "very fine",12_000.00F);
    comix[0].setPrice( (Float) quality.get(comix[0].condition) );
}
class Comic{
    String title;
    String issueNumber;
    String condition;
    float price;
    float basePrice;
    public Comic(String inTitle, String inIssueNumber, String inCondition, float inBasePrice){

        title = inTitle;
        issueNumber = inIssueNumber;
        condition = inCondition;
        basePrice = inBasePrice;
    }
    void setPrice(float factor){
        price = basePrice * factor;
    }
}
```

}

Those who have access to the book can see output on the page 235

Comment: I started with that very same book. Warning: you need a bit more than 21 days.

Comment: exactly its not possible to get it in 21 days but i'm on to it and not after days just learning on my own pace

Comment: Could you point out the line at which the error occurred?  Is it, by any chance, the one that starts with `comix[0] = new Comic(...`?

Comment: start with showing code that might compile. The code you posted won't

Comment: if i write full code will that work? i thought to add minimum code

Comment: '... following a book called "Learn java in 21 days"'. This was your first mistake. It takes years.

Comment: @user207421 at least they don't claim that you'll master Java in 21 days :)

Comment: ok guys i found it...its the wrong book i'm following cheers...you all won i lost...chill.